# Can copy file, can't add it Google script

Tags: google-apps-script

In a Google script, I have a folder object (testFolder) and a file object (testFile). I have these two lines of code:

testFolder.addFile(testFile);

testFile.makeCopy('this is a copy', testFolder);

The second line correctly copies the file into the folder.
The first line seems to do nothing. I'm expecting it to add a reference to the file and place it in the folder.

I obviously have the correct objects and I am the owner of the file and the folder, so any other ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make a copy create new file in Google Drive. But one cannot simply move a file into a folder. You have to make a copy into the desired folder and then remove the old file. Or you have to directly create the file in the desired folder location.

Comment: So, just to clarify, the file already exists, I'm using addFile(child) method of the folder object, which according to the reference guide: "Adds the given file to the current folder. This method does not move the file out of its existing parent folder; a file can have more than one parent simultaneously"

Answer (score 0):

What is your code for getting the 'testFile' and 'testFolder' objects? Are you referencing them by ID or by name? If you have multiple folders of the same name in your Google Drive, this could be causing the issue.  Here's the script that worked for me

```
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById('YOUR_FILE_ID');
  var folder1 = DriveApp.getFolderById("YOUR_FOLDER1_ID");
  var folder2 = DriveApp.getFolderById("YOUR_FOLDER2_ID");
  file.makeCopy('another copy', folder1);
  folder1.addFile(file);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this. The script creates the folder and the subfolders, so they are unique. The fact that the file is copied into the correct folder shows that I'm picking up the correct file and folder. I just can't seem to get it to add the file instead (like CRTL-Z menu 'Add to Folder' in the UI). The script is basically creating an employee folder and I want to add the company policy document to it. BUT I only want one master copy, so if it's changed, everybody gets to see it in their employee folder (because they are actually just looking at the same document). Does this make sense?

Comment: I understand that you want to add more than one parent folder to the file.  folder.addFile() worked like a charm for me, so the issue must be deeper. This doesn't even conflict with any sharing permissions as they are changed automatically

Comment: Yes that is completely correct. I'm stumped as the two lines of code that I have posted are sequential - the debugger appears to add the file (no error message) and then on the next line, successfully copies it. (I only put the copy in as a check, by the way).